# Tools that screenscrap my page always use the same image

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-opengraph

I have an ad block on the bottom that pulls my previous pages. Why does one image always get chosen (the giant twitter t)?  Check out http://reviewsie.com/movie/The-Grey for an example.

I fixed it in facebook and set the `og:image` tag to my logo.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Freviewsie.com%2Fmovie%2FThe-Grey) with your URL.  Using that tool refreshes Facebook's caching of your `og:tags`.
In addition I see there are some errors when scraping your URL with the Debugger - you need to fix those errors too.

Comment: Yeah, the image specified in `oh:image` is correct, but the page mostly return bad status code (503) for Debug tool.

Comment: Have you seen your URL in the debugger?